# Cambiar dinámicamente fichero en JS

Tags: javascript

Teniendo un fichero base en formato JSON :

```
{
    "id": "001;12;178;2022-06-0111:56:13;68",
    "time": "2022-05-31",
    "type": "",
    "dataContentType": "application/xml",
}
```

necesito cambiar el fichero dinámicamente modificando el valor de la clave "id" sumando, por ejemplo, un 1 al último número. Es decir: sumar 1 al 68. Quedaría entonces:

```
{
    "id": "001;12;178;2022-06-0111:56:13;69",
    "time": "2022-05-31",
    "type": "",
    "dataContentType": "application/xml",
}
```

Primero abro el fichero y luego necesito editarlo:

```
const data1 = open('./data/data-1.json')

   ---EDITAR valor de la clave id de data1---
}
```

No controlo demasiado de Javascript y no sé cómo resolverlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//vamos a editar un archivo json.json
var fs = require('fs');
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('json.json', 'utf8'));
//vamos a cambiar la id "id": "001;12;178;2022-06-0111:56:13;68", por la id "id": "001;12;178;2022-06-0111:56:13;69",
obj.id = "001;12;178;2022-06-0111:56:13;69";
//Guardamos el archivo JSON.json
fs.writeFileSync('json.json', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Espero que te vaya bien